# vhdl generic parameters used by other generic parameters (error: generic "parameter" is not visible here)

Tags: vhdl

In Verilog, I can define a parameter and then use it to define another parameter.  For example:

```
module stuff1 #(
   parameter AW = 16,
   parameter DW = 16,
   parameter FW = AW + DW + 2,
) (
    input   wire [AW-1:0]     adr,
    input   wire [DW-1:0]     dat,
    output  wire [FW-1:0]     fifo
);
endmodule
```

How can I do something similar in VHDL generic?  Example:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity stuff1 is
    generic(
        AW          : integer := 15;
        DW          : integer := 15;
        FW          : integer := AW + DW + 2
    );
    port(
        adr   : in    std_logic_vector(AW-1 downto 0);
        dat   : in    std_logic_vector(DW-1 downto 0);
        fifo  : out   std_logic_vector(FW-1 downto 0)
    );
end entity;

architecture rtl of stuff1 is
begin

end architecture;
```

When I try to compile this code, I get the following error in VHDL:

```
..\..\simtools\ghdl\bin\ghdl.exe -a bus_direct_server.vhdl
stuff1.vhdl: generic "aw" is not visible here
stuff1.vhdl: generic "dw" is not visible here
```

I'm wondering, is this possible in VHDL to automatically calculate FW parameter from AW and DW? or was Verilog more snazzy on this one occasion?

Comment: Because in VHDL 2002 and earlier, you cannot. In VHDL 2008, you can.

Comment: New to -2008, which ghdl does support. -1993 4.3.2.1 Interface lists "A name that denotes an interface object may not appear in any interface declaration within the interface list containing the denoted interface object except to declare this object."

Comment: The restriction showed up in -1993 to address [Issue Report 0089](http://www.eda-twiki.org/isac/IRs-VHDL-87/IR0089.txt). The added 4.3.2.1 language was introduced in Language Change Specification 0035 for VHDL-92. At the time no one knew the impact of subtypes specified in a generic map aspect on the elaboration of subsequent generic declarations depending on them. The restriction was the Ada way of dealing with it.

Comment: I'm wondering if its possible to get around this restriction by placing AW and FW parameters inside of a package and removing the generic port from the entity?

Comment: vhdl-93 work around ... create a wrapper entity around the above entity that has nothing but the FW parameter calculation.... then instantiate the above entity by explicitly specifying FW...  wait a second... that doesn't work...unless vhdl  has the feature of a collapsible/unbounded std_logic_vector ports that shrink to the size of the interface they are connected to... similar to the way the return of std_logic_vectors works in a function

Comment: another possible work around, place a function for calculating FW in a package, then place it on a signal bound in the port map?  possible?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if trick will pass synthesis, but it works in GHDL simulator.  First create a package with function to calculate fw from aw and dw parameters:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

package pkg_stuff1 is
    function fw_calc (aw: natural; dw: natural) return natural;
end package;

package body bus_direct is

    function fw_calc (aw: natural; dw: natural) return natural is
    begin
        return dw + aw + 2;
    end function;

end package body;
```

Once we have the package setup, then its a matter of using it:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
using work.pkg_stuff1.all;

entity stuff1 is
    generic(
        AW          : integer := 15;
        DW          : integer := 15
    );
    port(
        adr   : in    std_logic_vector(AW-1 downto 0);
        dat   : in    std_logic_vector(DW-1 downto 0);
        fifo  : out   std_logic_vector(fw_calc(aw, dw)-1 downto 0)
    );
end entity;

architecture rtl of stuff1 is
begin

end architecture;
```

Answer (score 0):

Why just you do you not do it like:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity stuff1 is
    generic(
        AW          : integer := 15;
        DW          : integer := 15;
    );
    port(
        adr   : in    std_logic_vector(AW-1 downto 0);
        dat   : in    std_logic_vector(DW-1 downto 0);
        fifo  : out   std_logic_vector(AW+DW+1 downto 0)
    );
end entity;

architecture rtl of stuff1 is
begin

end architecture;
```

I assume that there is a relationship between the input and output vectors that you want to keep. It seems like bad practice to have generic parameters with dependencies on other ones.

Comment: its a good point...that would work in many cases... but in my case it was too messy...

Comment: What are your use case? With 2008 you could run it unconstrained, as it looks like a sub module. You should only do this if you take great care.

Comment: my use case is that i'm using an old clunky ghdl.exe simulator that only supports vhdl-93... and Its too many things to add together...

Comment: Oh... I see. any particular reason to not use the free version of modelsim or xsim?

Comment: I liked that GHDL simulator executable is so small and portable that I can zip it in same directory as my VHDL code and store it canned with a powershell script that always works,..  its much less problematic then always needing to download modelsim or xsim and messing around with filling out request to downloadforms from intel and Xilinx,  and maybe we will let you download it...etc.. and the simulator applicant can't be stored with the VHDL code the same way as GHDL... I just load my zip file  with GHDL simulator and VHDL code on a thumb drive and I can work on any computer.